# Select unique/distinct combination of values from IEnumerable of same type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have three IEnumerables of the same type (string) and I want to get unique combinations of values from it. Not quite sure how to implement LINQ in here.

[image: Input data would look like this, one column represents one IEnum]

The result should be a list of something like this by adding - as separator

a-p-1
b-q-4
b-r-7
c-s-8
c-s-9
d-t-10
e-u-11

Data itself is in unique connection. All projects in one account are unique, and so does all subprojects for a particular project.

Comment: He has three collections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not be storing related items in separate sequences; that's an antipattern. However, if this happens to be the way that your data is available, you can first combine the items from the sequences using `Zip`, then use `Distinct` to get unique values.

```
var result = accounts.Zip(projects, (a, p) => a + "-" + p)
                     .Zip(subprojects, (a, s) => a + "-" + s)
                     .Distinct()
                     .ToList();
```

**Edit**: In the spirit of [Servy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21050692/1149773), here is an extension method for zipping an arbitrary number of sequences:

```
public static partial class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> Zip<TSource, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> sequences,
        Func<IEnumerable<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector)
    {
        var enumerators = sequences.Select(sequence => sequence.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
        while (enumerators.All(enumerator => enumerator.MoveNext()))
            yield return resultSelector(enumerators.Select(enumerator => enumerator.Current));
    }
}
```

And this is how it would be consumed:

```
string[][] sequences = { accounts, projects, subprojects };
var results = sequences.Zip(items => string.Join("-", items))
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, didn't realize it could be this way as well. Thanks.
I was making it too complicated. :-)

Comment: I would select it as an answer again and again if I could. (Since I already did select it as an answer) Thanks @Douglas and Servy...

Answer (score 3):

While you could use `Zip` twice to zip three sequences, creating a new three way zip is easy enough and will be easier to work with:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> TriZip<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> first,
    IEnumerable<TSource> second,
    IEnumerable<TSource> third,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    using (var firstIterator = first.GetEnumerator())
    using (var secondIterator = second.GetEnumerator())
    using (var thirdIterator = third.GetEnumerator())
        while (firstIterator.MoveNext() &&
            secondIterator.MoveNext() &&
            thirdIterator.MoveNext())
            yield return resultSelector(firstIterator.Current,
                secondIterator.Current,
                thirdIterator.Current);
}
```

Now your work is pretty much just calling this method, plus a `Distinct`:

```
var query = accounts.TriZip(projects, subprojects,
    (account, project, subproject) => 
        new { account, project, subproject })
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Pretty sophisticated way of doing this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is correct to create a TriZip but it then restricts to only three IEnums. I mean does not really generalize things, with zip one can add multiple IEnums. On the other hand, it's really great to use if I am encountering this triple combination multiple times. +1